# Spaces between mdframed and tabularx

Tags: tabularx, mdframed, layout

I'm building a sort of information sheet, and do to that I'm using a combinaison of `tabularx` (for small text frames) and `mdframed` (for long text+formatting frames.

The problem happens in the space between those 2 structures.
I cannot manage to set this correclty, and moreover it varies bewteen the instances.

I need color and line formatting as presented in the MWE, hence my usage of tabularx, but I'm open to other solutions.

Here on the picture, you can see that the spacing is not coherent.
[image: MWE output]

Here is the MWE :

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{cellspace}
%\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

\usepackage[defaultfam,tabular,lining]{montserrat} 

\renewcommand*\oldstylenums[1]{{\fontfamily{Montserrat-TOsF}\selectfont #1}}

\mdfdefinestyle{MyFrame}{%
    linecolor=red,
    outerlinewidth=1.5pt,
    innertopmargin=\baselineskip,
    innerbottommargin=\baselineskip,
    innerrightmargin=10pt,
    innerleftmargin=10pt,
    skipabove=0pt,
    skipbelow=0pt}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}


\begin{document}

    {\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{12pt}
        \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{12pt}
        \setlength\arrayrulewidth{2pt}
        \noindent
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{!{\color{red}\vrule width 2pt}m{2cm}!{\color{red}\vrule width 2pt}S{X}!{\color{red}\vrule width 2pt}}
            \arrayrulecolor{red} \hline
            ID &  Title of the frame \\\hline%
        \end{tabularx}%
    }%
    {\setlength\arrayrulewidth{2pt} 
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{!{\color{red}\vrule width 2pt}*3{Y}!{\color{red}\vrule width 2pt}}
            \arrayrulecolor{red} \hline
            \rowcolor{lightgray}  1 &  2 & 3\\ \hline
        \end{tabularx}%
    }%
    \begin{mdframed}[style=MyFrame, frametitle={Title} ]
            Here we will have a long text, possibly more paragraphs that needs to fit in the tableHere we will have a long text, possibly more paragraphs that needs to fit in the tableHere we will have a long text, possibly more paragraphs that needs to fit in the tableHere we will have a long tere we will have a long text, possibly more paragraphs that needs to fit in the tableHere we will have a long text, possibly more paragraphs that needs to fit in the tableHere we will have a long text, possibly more paragraphs that needs to fit in the tableHere we will have a long text, possibly more paragraphs that needs to fit in the table

            Here we will have a long text, possibly more paragraphs that needs to fit in the tableHere we will have a long text, possibly more paragraphs that needs to fit in the tableHere we will have a long text, possibly more paragraphs that needs to fit in the tableHere we will have a long tere we will have a long text, possibly more paragraphs that needs to fit in the tableHere we will have a long text, possibly more paragraphs that needs to fit in the tableHere we will have a long text, possibly more paragraphs that needs to fit in the tableHere we will have a long text, possibly more paragraphs that needs to fit in the table
    \end{mdframed}% 
    {\setlength\arrayrulewidth{2pt}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{!{\color{red}\vrule width 2pt}S{X}!{\color{red}\vrule width 2pt}}  
            \arrayrulecolor{red} \hline
                \textbf{Test:} {John Doe}
                \\ \hline
        \end{tabularx}
    }%
    \begin{mdframed}[style=MyFrame, frametitle={Information} ]      
        Here we will have a long text, possibly more paragraphs that needs to fit in the table
        \vspace{3pt}
    \end{mdframed}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Could you precise how the spacing should look like?

Comment: Well I don't know as long as I have a mean to control it and that its equal between all the frames (tabularx and mdframed env).

Comment: I've tried with `\vspaces` but it doesn't work, even without them the spaces is not the same and I don't know where it comes from.